# Response with status: null null for URL: null error when testing http post service

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

Testing the http post service. But the test fails with the following error 
Expected object to be a kind of Object, but was Response with status: null null for URL: null.

I tried adding the url to RequestOptions but it gave an error. what could be the problem I can't seem to figure it out

// test file

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, getTestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { HttpPostService } from './http-post.service';
import {
  BaseRequestOptions, Http, XHRBackend, HttpModule,
  Response, ResponseOptions, RequestMethod
} from '@angular/http';
import { ICourseModel } from '../interface/course-model';

describe('HttpPostService', () => {
  let mockBackend: MockBackend;


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        HttpPostService,
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        {
          provide: Http,
          deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions],
          useFactory:
          (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
            return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
          }
        }
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpModule
      ]
    });
    mockBackend = getTestBed().get(MockBackend);
  }));

  it('should insert new courseList',
    async(inject([HttpPostService], (service: HttpPostService) => {
      mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
        expect(connection.request.method).toBe(RequestMethod.Post);
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({})));
        const contentType = connection.request.headers.get('Content-Type');
        expect(contentType).not.toBeNull();
        expect(contentType).toEqual('application/json');
        expect(connection.request.url).toBe('someurl/data.json');
      });
      const courseList: ICourseModel[] = [
        { 'course': 'Mobile Development' },
        { 'course': 'Web Development' },
        { 'course': 'IOS Development' },
        { 'course': 'Android Development' }
      ];
      const result = service.storeData(courseList);
      result.subscribe(
        (successResult) => {
          expect(successResult).toBeDefined();
          expect(successResult).toEqual({});
        });
    })));
});
```

// http post service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { ICourseModel } from '../interface/course-model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

// HTTP Post service to post the data to the server. Add Content-type in the header while posting a data
@Injectable()
export class HttpPostService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  storeData(crs: ICourseModel[]) {
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('someurl/data.json', crs, {headers: headers}).catch(
      (error: Response) => {
        return Observable.throw(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating things. Don't test if `http.post` works (angular team did that); test if your service is calling `http.post` correctly. This should be enough for your service:

```ts
describe('HttpPostService', () => {
  let service: HttpPostService;
  let http;
  const testError = new Error('Test Error');
  const courseList: ICourseModel[] = [
    { 'course': 'Mobile Development' },
    { 'course': 'Web Development' },
    { 'course': 'IOS Development' },
    { 'course': 'Android Development' }
  ];

  beforeEach(() => {
    http = jasmine.createSpyObject('http', ['post']);
    service = new HttpPostService(http);
  });

  it('should work', () => {
    service.storeData(courseList);
    expect(http.post
      .toHaveBeenCalledWith('someurl/data.json', courseList, jasmine.any(Object));
  });

  it('should throw', () => {
    http.post.and.returnValue(Observable.throw(testError));
    // since you're not handling error in HttpPostService, 
    // you don't need to test catch(), 
    // but if there was a HttpPostService.errorHanlder test would be:
    spyOn(service, 'errorHandler');
    service.storeData(courseList);
    expect(service.errorHandler).toHaveBeenCalledWith(testError);
  });
});
```

You can find out more about [jasmine spies](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies).

Comment: i don't want to but this is my assignment so I have to. Can you please answer with my code. thanks for your help

Comment: Then I'd suggest to have a look at official tests and their setup: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/http/test/http_spec.ts

Comment: and i have one more query, how do you check the 'Content-type' of response in tests